# ¿Como conectar net core con mysql?

Tags: mysql, c#, asp.net

Espero me puedan apoyar, estoy tratando de conectar una aplicacion net core con una base de datos pero a la hora depurar no me da nada, se queda cargando. No se que me este faltando, ya agregue la dependencia `MySql.Data`

Este es mi controlador:

```
 public async Task<IActionResult> Index()
    {
        var usuarios = await repositorioUsuario.ObtenerUsuarios();
        return View(usuarios);
    }
```

Este es mi Servicio:

```
public interface IRepositorioUsuario
{
    Task<IEnumerable<Usuario>> ObtenerUsuarios();
}

public class RepositorioUsuario: IRepositorioUsuario
{
    private readonly string connectionString;
    public RepositorioUsuario(IConfiguration configuration)
    {
        connectionString = configuration.GetConnectionString("AMLCC");
    }

    public async Task<IEnumerable<Usuario>> ObtenerUsuarios()
    {
        using var connection = new MySqlConnection(connectionString);
        return await connection.QueryAsync<Usuario>("select * from usuario", commandType:CommandType.Text);
    }

}
```

Asi esta mi archivo appsettings.json:

```
"ConnectionStrings": {
"AMLCC": "Server=localhost;Port=8081;Database=prueba;Uid=root;"
```

}

Espero me puedan apoyar.

Answer (score 1):

Estuve investigando y vi que aparte de necesitar `MySql.Data`, necesito el paquete de `MySqlConnector`, espero les pueda ayudar.